# Merge UnTyped DataSets to Typed DataSet

Tags: strongly-typed-dataset

i have two datatable in Typed DataSet
named tblA and tblB

note: both the table is having different data structure.

let me know how to merge two untyped dataset to the above typed dataset.

```
Dear Tony,
Thanks for your effort. 
But please understand my question.

I have 2 DataTable in Typed DataSet 
DataTable names are: tblA and tblB

Now i have to merge Untyped Dataset one by one.

i need to map and merge.
Like:

UnTypedDATASET.TABLE("TABLEONE")

NOW LET ME KNOW HOW TO MERGE THIS WITH TYPEDDATASET.TABLE("tblA")

i did like this: TypedDataSet.merge(DS.table("tblA"))
but its mapping to tblB instead of tblA

Expecting your valuable help.
```

Comment: Are you saying you have more than one table in the untyped dataset as well? If so extract them out one by one in to another dataset and then merge that. Note if your tables have similar schemas Merge can't figure out which is which unless they are all strongly typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got a solution to merge UNTYPED DATASET WITH TYPED DATASET**

```
Typed_DS.Tables("tblA").Merge(UnTyped_DS.Tables("tablename"), True, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
```

Regards,
Thiru.

Answer (score 0):

```
myTypedDataset.Merge(myUntypedDataset)
```

Not being funny but this is two second google.

Comment: Dear Tony,
Thanks for your effort. 
But please understand my question.

I have 2 DataTable in Typed DataSet 
DataTable names are: tblA and tblB

Now i have to merge Untyped Dataset one by one.

i need to map and merge.
Like:

UnTypedDATASET.TABLE("TABLEONE")

NOW LET ME KNOW HOW TO MERGE THIS WITH TYPEDDATASET.TABLE("tblA")

i did like this: TypedDataSet.merge(DS.table("tblA"))
but its mapping to tblB instead of tblA

Expecting your valuable help.

Comment: Are you SHOUTING at me? If you are I don't like it. Bear something in mind in here and in life. It's not mu fault I'm not understanding you. Based on your expansion to the question, I may have a look once I get over being irritated...

Comment: Dear Tony, Sorry if i did wrong and i didn't shout at all... more over i am happy with you that i am getting your reply for my post.  Please let me know where you found me shouting ?   - I just explain you more clear with example.

Comment: Oh my god. Dear Tony, i am from India. we use the capital letters to highlight the sentence. So, please ignore that - i really didn't mean like shouting. i just try to highlight and make more clearer on that part.  Hope u understand - pls. reply in this regard.

Comment: Okey dokey, a cultural difference, no problem. I've added a request for clarification to your question.